# Add additional checkout step to send mail

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout

i need to add an extra step in magento one page checkout before the payment information step. this step basically includes a form to collect some user info which is later sent through mail to the admin when the order is placed. how can i implement this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Questions on stackoverflow must be programming related, and should show what you have tried and why it didnt work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This work cannot be done in a single step,so i cannot provide you a complete answer but a guide can be helpfull to start.

You need to extend Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage::getSteps(), where you add your new step.

Create new step template, Your block class will extend from : Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract

you also need to update onepagecheckout jquery so that AJAX call which load your step will work.

Also you will need to extend the controller class (Mage_Checkout_OnepageController) so that the content of your new step from the template, and also the save action of your step will handled here.

This is an excellent guide for more ref :

http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-add-step

Regards